# Android Airplane mode setting

Tags: android

I have modified onAirplaneModeChanged() in AirplaneModeEnabler.java.
The method now reads the status of airplane mode directly from the
database. When i enter the wireless settings screen, the checkbox is
checked/unchecked as expected.

But when I switch the airplane mode to ON, the airplane mode checkbox
gets checked instantly. But the list-item "airplane mode" is disabled.

The disabling happens through setAirplaneModeOn() called in
onAirplaneModeChanged().

This behaviour is not observed when SIM is inserted.

In short, here is my question: setAirplaneModeOn() sets the summary
and disables the item. When and where will the item get enabled again?

Regards,
Webgenius